# Rally - Failing to connect via pyral as a project admin, same code works for workspace admin

Tags: rally

I am able to connect to rally as a workspace admin using user, password, and hosturl.

```
rally = Rally("10.xxx.xxx.xxx",
"xxx@xxx.com",
"xxx", version="2.0",
verify_ssl_cert = False)
```

But when I try to use a project admin instead I am getting an exception thrown:
    self._defaultProject = proj_names[0]
      IndexError: list index out of range

The user is a valid user and has editor and project admin access in different projects in the same workspace. There are multiple workspaces.

I am using pyral 1.0.0 and requests 2.3.0

Answer (score 1):

There are cases when a WS API workspaces and projects endponts gives TotalResultCount that is larger than the number of objects WS API actually returns. The latter depends on user's access. That is why whenever there is a discrepancy the number of returned objects is less than the total number.  See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23997434/call-to-rally-api-v2-0-not-returning-consistent-results) for details.

Pyral 1.0 caches data from workspaces endpoint on subscription and projects endpoint on workspace, before it even executes your code. But it runs into this discrepancy between the TotalResultCount and the actual number of objects returned, and it does not recover.

The new version of pyral that may be out in about a week is expected to work around this problem.

Comment: I read the link you provided and the answer for now appears to be to downgrade pyral to 0.9.4 and the API to 1.42.

Comment: yes,downgrading pyral to 0.9.4, which uses WS API prior to v2.0, should workaround this problem.